# Bootstrap 4 Not Centering Correctly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm not really sure how I center the `h2`, it's my first time using bootsrap 4 after I've used Bootstrap 3 so maybe there's a difference? I'm not sure, but any help would be... helpful. Thanks!

```
<nav class="container navbar navbar-expand-md justify-content-end">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container row introduction justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2>Made to order DIY projects<br>for all your home decor<br>needs!</h2>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

As you see, the text is not centered at all and I don't know how to fix it... Maybe I'm using the wrong bootstrap? I'm not sure

Comment: Your introduction container is not occupying the full width of the viewport.

Comment: try this - `<div class="container"><div class="text-center"><h2>Made to order DIY projects<br>for all your home decor<br>needs!</h2></div></div>`

Comment: What does that mean? How would I fix this?

Comment: I tried the 'text-center' but it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

using a div as row it works very [well](https://jsfiddle.net/n1dske6w/)

```
<nav class="container navbar navbar-expand-md justify-content-end">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container introduction ">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <h2>Made to order DIY projects<br>for all your home decor<br>needs!</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

All the best

Comment: This code made it so one word was on a different row, as if it was in a single column

Comment: @ssethzz ok, now its better, bye ;)

Comment: obviously it can works also using container and row at the same level, mixing classes, but bootstap layouts is designed to use container, rows and columns, regards

Comment: It keeps doing the same thing ;'(

Answer (score 1):

You are using `grid system` the `col-md-6` is half of the one row so the text is centerd within left column

if want to center a text in the row remove the `col-md-6` and add the text in container like below

```
<div class="container row introduction">
    <h2 class="text-center">Made to order DIY projects<br>for all your home decor<br>needs!</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: This code made it move to the left still

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me Bootstrap 4.3.1

```
<div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <form class="col-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Example label</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Example input">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Another label</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Another input">
          </div>
        </form>   
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some previous answer do work, that made me think you are using bootstrap 5 instead. regardless, this should work for both 4 and 5

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row row-cols-1 justify-content-center">
      <div class="col text-center w-auto">
        <h2>Made to order DIY projects<br>for all your home decor<br>needs!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```